# Scott Mountain bike. Problem with pedaling

Tags: crankset

Last 2 runs out my bike I have as suffered from what I can only describe as the pedal free wheeling ie pressure put on pedal does not drive the bike, but after a couple of turns it then drive the bike forward. New cassette and chain installed by bike shop 2 years ago, only used once a week but in a fairly steep inclined countryside on short outings ie mountains. advice appreciated.

Comment: Check the freewheel/freehub mechanism (depending on if you have a freewheel and cassette) - it may be on its way out.

Comment: Yeah, probably the freewheel/freehub mechanism is slipping.  This is more likely in cold weather, or if the bike is not used much, but generally will get worse.  Occasionally the mechanism can be cleaned to fix it (the problem is likely gummy lube inside) but the usual repair is to replace the unit.

Comment: I think you are right re the slipping in the hub, in fact have ordered new rear wheel and tool today. Thanks vm for you advice

Answer (score 2):

This can happen easily when a new chain is installed with a cassette that is worn, but you would likely notice that it's the chain skipping in this case.

It sounds like the culprit is the engagement system inside of the hub of your rear wheel. The engagement system has teeth that lock when you pedal, and if too many of these teeth become worn you won't get any power transfer, it sounds like this is your most likely culprit. I've had this happen before, and it tends to only get worse. If it seems like this is what's happening, take the rear wheel into the shop and see what they can do for you.

[image: rear hub cutaway]